# How can handle foreign words in C++ code?

Tags: visual-c++, encoding, character-encoding

I recently download some C++ source code which is written by Russian. When I open the project in my MSVC(VC2008 Chinese edition), the comments of codes is  hard too see. And When I compile the code, it generates many many warnings and errors.
such as this case:
    "error C2001: newline in constant"

```
TCHAR text[]=_T("卿羼?祛驽?猁螯 忄 疱觌囔?);
```

I think people who use Windows OS Russian edition may not meet this problem. The Problem is, how can I handle **foreign languages** in this occasion ? I want to display the code and comments rightly in my VC++ IDE, and thus can compile the codes, how to achieve this goal?

I feel sorry that I don't know whether I explained this problem clearly or not, and the title of this problem is properly?

Comment: the display of different charsets is the responsibility of the windows, in addition to that try to set the project to use Unicode libraries

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert all code files from CP1251 (or KOI8-R, not sure, have to try) to any Unicode encoding, like UTF-8 with BOM. Notepad++ could be used for this, but Visual Studio can also be used:

Open files in Visual Studio, but instead of just double-clicking them do: right-click in Solution Explorer > Open With... > C++ source code editor (with encoding) > "Cyrillic (Windows) - Codepage 1251" (or some other Cyrillic encoding).

To save the file in Unicode encoding do: File menu > Save  As... > click on triangle sign within Save button and choose Save with Encoding... > confirm overwrite > choose any Unicode encoding, like "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001".